# listening to UDP broadcasts with HTML5 and or JS

Tags: html, google-chrome, udp

I programmed an ESP32 server that between others, creates and broadcasts UDP datagrams. The question is, if and how I can receive these from my client (a mobile device) running an HTML/JS program in Chrome or Safari browser. I am only interested in receiving the datagrams, it doesn't seem to be documented. I could use XMLhttprequests but all clients need the same data so it makes sense to send it to all at once.

Thank you in advance

PS: Chrome had an API (chrome.sockets.udp) that was part of the deprecated Chrome Apps platform, and anyway was not available to JS.

Answer (score 0):

Through Apache2. Both the ESP Server and web browsers can interface with it. https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?t=4840 Or you could use something like ENet to use applications/programs without a web interface: http://enet.bespin.org/

Comment: This approach is using POST and GET requests (XMLhttprequests) and requires that each client is connected. This is the method I am currently using. The problem is, I need to send the datagram to each connected client separately. UDP broadcasts on the other hand are send and whoever is listening, is receiving them. No need to connect to, nor ask for the data.

Comment: You could possibly enumerate each user by their IP address and send seperate datagrams to each client with asynchronization. But that is not exactly how POST and GET requests are supposed to work. Perhaps Node.JS has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

After trying hard to find a way to access UDP broadcasts by a browser I'm convinced that it is impossible, by the design of the browsers.